# Display call duration / times in WP8?

Tags: 8.0, history

Some posts in [this thread](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/210477-5.htm) suggest that it isn't possible in WP8 to see how long each call took.

Is this true? How do I check when done calls were made and how long they took?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - as mentioned in comments this is now possible with 8.1. Press and hold on a call and tap 'details.'

Comment: Wow. Another "phone basics" fail. I'm very disappointed any time I find something that any smartphone can't do, which I used to be able to do on my flip-phone.

Comment: [Fixed in 8.1](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5558/1046)