# Call start time in call history

Tags: nokia-lumia-820, history

I want to look up what time my friend called me on my nokia 820, so I go to call history. Yet it looks like times are only shown for the calls in last week. Before that I can only see a date. Is there any way to change the datetime format for these and/or see the call start times for older calls?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to see the call start time for calls made more than one week ago, nor the duration of the calls made, like explained [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/display-call-duration-times-in-wp8).

Let's hope that Windows Phone will soon offer this kind of (basic!) functions...

Answer (score 2):

With Windows Phone 8.1, press and hold on a "Call History" item and select "details". The details screen will show the date, time, and duration of the call(s) represented by that item.